# Does FirefoxDriver.getPageSource() return the modified, or initial, DOM?

Tags: firefox, selenium

The [JavaDoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getPageSource%28%29) for `WebDriver.getPageSource()` states that

> Get the source of the last loaded page. If the page has been modified
>   after loading (for example, by Javascript) there is no guarentee that
>   the returned text is that of the modified page. Please consult the
>   documentation of the particular driver being used to determine whether
>   the returned text reflects the current state of the page or the text
>   last sent by the web server. /.../

I am using `FirefoxDriver` ([JavaDoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html)) but can't find any information about this. It is returning the modified DOM or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be returning the modified DOM. If it is not, we probably have a bug that should get logged here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/entry